# No funciona redireccionamiento en Angular al hacer logout

Tags: angular

Tengo mi archivo apiauth.service.ts de la siguiente manera:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { BehaviorSubject,  map,  Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Usuario } from "../models/usuario";
import { Response } from "../models/response";
import { Login } from "../models/login";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
const httpOption = {
   headers :new HttpHeaders({
  
  
     'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
   })
 }
@Injectable({
   providedIn:'root'
})
export class ApiAuthService{
  url: string = 'https://localhost:44355/User/Login' ;
  private usuarioSubject!: BehaviorSubject<Usuario>;
  public usuario: Observable<Usuario>;
  public get usuarioData():Usuario{

    return this.usuarioSubject.value;
  
  }
  constructor(private router:Router,private http : HttpClient){
       this.usuarioSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Usuario>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario')!));
       this.usuario = this.usuarioSubject.asObservable();
  }
  login(login : Login):Observable<Response>{
      return this.http.post<Response>(this.url, login,httpOption).pipe(map(res=>{
  
        if(res.exito == 1){

           const usuario:Usuario = res.data;
           localStorage.setItem('usuario',JSON.stringify(usuario));
           this.usuarioSubject.next(usuario);
        }
        return res;
      }));
 
  }
  logout(){
   
    localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
}
```

Pero si doy click en el boton cerrar sesion, no me redirige al login ni a ninguna pagina. Y los datos se siguen visualizando..Sin embargo si refresco la pagina(con el navegador o F5) si me aparece el login y ya no puedo entrar a ningun controller.. que podra ser?

Edito: app.routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticuloComponent } from './articulo/articulo.component';
import { ClienteComponent } from './cliente/cliente.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { VentaComponent } from './venta/venta.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  
  {path: 'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path: 'Clientes',component:ClienteComponent},
  {path: 'Venta',component:VentaComponent},
  {path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'Articulo',component:ArticuloComponent},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Puedes publicar el modulo de rutas?.  Y prueba agregando la ruta absoluta del login , por ejemplo `this.router.navigate(["/login"])`

Comment: Ya probé como dices y sigue iguall

Comment: Publica el modulo de rutas para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Listo ahi publique el routing module

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 3 rutas que chocan. `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }`, `{path: '', component: HomeComponent}` y `{path: 'home',component:HomeComponent}`

```js
  
  {path: 'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path: 'Clientes',component:ClienteComponent},
  {path: 'Venta',component:VentaComponent},
  {path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'Articulo',component:ArticuloComponent},
  // Este no => {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
  //Redirije a tu home si no hay nada escrito. Es más natural. 
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  //Agrega esto en caso de que estemos teniendo un error. 
  { path: '**', component:NotFoundComponent },
```

Ahora `this.router.navigate(["/login"])` no debería de darte ningún problema.

Comment: hola..aplique el codigo que pusiste pero sigue igual, que puede ser

Comment: Agrega una nueva ruta `path:'**'` a un componente que quieras (puede ser uno que muestre un error 404)  Puede que te este mandando un error y con esa linea se captura el error..

Comment: No sera que el login tiene que estar fuera de la aplicacion en la pantalla principal digamos

Comment: Esto te pasa en producción o en local?

Comment: En local. Pero al ver el login se ve el menu es decir esta dentro de appcomponent

Comment: Posiblemente tegas que reestructurar. Tienes que tener un pages.module, donde estaran tus contenidos, y a esa altura debes tener la ruta del login. de manera que quede `/login`, y `/` => dirigiendo a pages.module (con lazy load de preferencia)